# Start new project, time-locked wallet - Clarity Smart Contracts for Stacks

Tags: stack, blockchain, smartcontracts, clarity-lang, stacks-blockchain

Going thru the Clarity Code track. When creating a new Project, as you see the time-locked wallet, it didn't create it's own new project column, it went under Counter, the previous project.

resulting in timelocked-wallet.clar falling under Counter contracts and not timelocked-wallet contracts. Any word on keeping projects compartmentalized? is this an issue? Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Clarinet will create a directory in whatever is the current directory when you run the command.

You also have to be in project root when creating a contract.  If you are anywhere else it creates the directories and config file off the current directory and will mess up your structure.